# Showing that $\frac{\cos(\theta)-1}{\sin(\theta)}=-\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})$

Tags: trigonometry

> Show that $$\frac{\cos(\theta)-1}{\sin(\theta)} = -\tan \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$

I tried to I tried many substitutions with  $\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}=\frac{1}{\tan(\theta)}$ but fail to get to the correct direction. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how did you get from $\theta$ to $x$?

Comment: Does $x=\theta$?

Comment: $$\frac{\cos(\theta)-1}{\sin(\theta)}=\frac{-2\sin^2(\theta/2)}{2\sin(\theta/2)\cos(\theta/2)}=-\tan(\theta/2)$$